Texture painting black artifacts in render mode but not in viewport
I tried sculpture for the first time, then I wanted to try my hand at texture painting. Everything is going well so far but in render mode I have these black artifacts everywhere, yet in viewport I don't see them. Do you have any idea of ​​the problem?

Are you sure there isn’t a second mesh that you hid and forgot about?

What @TheLabCat said... I'm pretty sure it is the object called "Cube" which is hidden in viewport but not in render. The fact that the head object is called "Retopo_Cube" does indicate that as well in my opinion.
